# notfoundhttp exception while post request

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have researched all the previous answers of this similar question, yet I couldnt found any.

I am simply accessing the function which I have made custom

**Routes**

```
Route::post('dashboard', 'Admin\UserController@index');
```

**UserController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Session;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        echo "welcome"

    }
}
```

When I am trying this,it throws me

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

error.
**Update**

My all routes are

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

// Authentication routes...
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');

// Dashboard routes
Route::post('dashboard', 'Admin\UserController@index');
Route::controllers([
   'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Comment: `Admin` is dir name before controller ??

Comment: `php artisan route:list` Check the Routes list where is problem

Answer (score 0):

namespace you need to add Admin in your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
```

Since in your route you have Admin

```
Route::post('dashboard', 'Admin\UserController@index');
```

Updated

As per your comment you are accessing via
`http://localhost/travelling/dashboard` but if you are using localhost then you have to add public

```
http://localhost/travelling/public/dashboard
```

Also make sure since its POST reuqest you cant access Url directly from the browser.you need to use curl or html form with csrf token

**Update** 
Since you have added  `$this->middleware('auth');` in constructor so you have to login

Comment: Why? Cn u please explain?

Comment: can you show which url you are accessing and which route

Comment: Is your `usercontroller` is under `admin` diretory? @JayminNoob

Comment: @B.Desai already said if your controllers not in app\http\controllers\Admin then you have to remvoe admin from both

Comment: Yes my folder structure is app/Http/Controllers/Admin/UserController.php

Comment: localhost/travelling/public/dashboard.if you are using localhost you need to add public

Comment: Didn't worked I have mentioned that in routes so it should work right?

Comment: i didnt got .if oyu are usning localhost then you to access like  localhost/travelling/public/dashboard.unless if you are creating virtualhost

Comment: Is your request is `post`? @JayminNoob

Comment: since its a post request you need to access via ajax or html form with token

Comment: Yes @B.Desai it is post request

Comment: you need to be authenticated user since you have added middleware  $this->middleware('auth');

Answer (score 0):

As You mentioned the issue its Not Getting the Path of Controller in namespace:

*Try To Change namespace with this*
 `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;`

and your Routes will be like this: `Route::post('dashboard', 'UserController@index');`

Comment: @JayminNoob Change the Routes also

Comment: @B.Desai i didn't do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156013/discussion-between-jaymin-noob-and-rishikesh-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

In the UserController you have used

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

which is not correct with the route you are using. It should be namespace

```
App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
```

Secondly, it will be proper if you have the route of dashboard as get:

```
Route::get('dashboard', 'Admin\UserController@index');
```

Routes

```
Route::post('dashboard', 'Admin\UserController@index');
```

UserController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use DB;
use Session;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller 
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        echo "welcome"

    }
}
```

Comment: tried not worked infact my all routes are not working

Comment: have you written directly in the routes/web.php and checked it?